# Webpack hot module replacement (HMR) sourcemaps not updated / new code not visible in dev tools

Tags: webpack, source-maps, webpack-hmr

I have set up HMR successfully, everything working, including proxying the backend site. The only issue remaining is, that I can't see the actual original code (ES2015) in the browser unless I do a full reload.

Did I miss something or is this not possible? I use `'cheap-module-eval-source-map'`, tried `'cheap-module-inline-source-map'`. Is it even possible to provide sourcemaps in replaced modules, because they have to be evaluated?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome 47. Did you get refreshing of source-maps to work with HMR?

Answer (score 3):

There is an issue with HMR and updating the source maps in the DevTools. Typically, the source maps are cached by the browsers and since HMR does not trigger a full page reload, you are stuck with the outdated source map.
As a workaround, you can reload the Chrome DevTools pressing `alt+r`. Apparently this works with `cheap-module-source-map`.

See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2478 for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Use `webpack-dev-server -d --hot --inline`

`-d` is shorthand for `--debug --devtool source-map --output-pathinfo`

`--hot` is for hot replacement of modules

And then dev-server will start generating sourcemaps and inject code on every change

Answer (score 1):

`-d` is a shortcut for the command below in `webpack v.4.8.3`

```
--debug --devtool cheap-module-eval-source-map --output-pathinfo
```

https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#shortcuts

The thing that fixed it for me was setting the following in `webpack.config.js`:

```
devtool: "cheap-module-eval-source-map",
```